# What is the difference between 言語一般 and 一般言語?

Tags: meaning, translation

I was reading an article about 統語論 which was defined  as follows:

> 言語一般において文が構成される仕組みを扱う分野｡

Now when I tried to search for the meaning of "言語一般" I could not find any thing on it.
When I asked a native he give me this example:

> 言語一般でいえば時制の概念が存在すると考えてよいだろう。しかしながら、一口に時制と言っても、その詳細については言語毎に異なる場合がある。例えば過去形においては・・・

I still could not understand it. So, what is the difference?

Comment: Nothing in your text mentions 一般言語. I'm confused as to what you are asking about.

Comment: What is the difference between 言語一般 and 一般言語? i uderstand what  一般言語 means and asking about  言語一般

Comment: What exactly did you ask the native speaker to get that answer?? It doesn't seem to be an answer to what you are asking here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

言語一般 is like "languages in general", i.e., it's not about some specific language like Japanese but about all languages. Its antonym is 特定の言語. 言語一般 is not a set phrase; you can also say 政治家一般 ("politicians in general"), キリン一般 ("giraffes in general") and so on. 統語論 is not about one specific language but a cross-language study. 言語一般でいえば is "Speaking of languages in general, ..." or "Cross-linguistically, ...".

一般言語 is essentially a short version of 一般的な言語, and it's like "generic language", "ordinary language" or "general-purpose language". It's not a set phrase, either, but it may be used as opposed to some specialized, special, local or [domain-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) language. Depending on the context, its antonym would be something like 特化型言語, 固有言語 or 特殊言語.

By the way, 一般**の**言語 is ambiguous and may refer to anything above.